# how do i call javascript function at the end of button click in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I tried

```
Protected Sub btn_add_question_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_add_question.Click
        frm_course.Visible = False
        question_div.Visible = True
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(btn_add_question, Me.GetType(), "BlockName", "alert('hello world');", True)
    End Sub
```

and

```
Protected Sub btn_add_question_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_add_question.Click
        frm_course.Visible = False
        question_div.Visible = True
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "Javascript", "alert('hello')")
    End Sub
```

But, alert message is not showing. Need Help !!

```
 <asp:Button ID="btn_add_question" runat="server" Text="Next" CssClass="btn_submit" Width="101px" />
```

Comment: Use view source on the resultant page and search for `alert` -- how does it look?

Comment: Also, please post the asp code for the button, that might have an error too.

Comment: didn't found any `alert`

Comment: please check, i have updated the button code in my post

Comment: If you don't see alert in the source then this button is not being rendered.  Are you sure this control isn't inside another control that is being "hidden"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `<script>` tags to the function call by passing `True` as the last parameter to `RegisterStartupScript` as so:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "Javascript", "alert('hello');",True)
```

**UPDATE**:

Try this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "Javascript", "alert('hello');",True)
```

Comment: Not helpful, same as it was earlier.

Comment: i have noticed one thing that, when i commented the `frm_course.Visible = False` then it showing the alert box, now why i don't know, anybody please explain

Comment: @coders That doesn't make sense. There should be something else going on. Are you using any sort of UpdatePanel/ScriptManager in your page? I am confident that any of my 2 options will work on pages with updatepagel/scriptmanager and pages without them.

Comment: yes i accept, your solution is working, but only when i put `frm_course.Visible = False`  line inside the comment. That is why, i'm confused, why is that so.

Comment: I have the feeling `frm_course` is your main form and `RegisterStartupScript` is adding the script inside this form. Since it's invisible is not rendering anything and your script is not firing.

Answer (score -2):

add an `OnClientClick` handler to the button or, better yet, attach the handler through javascript where it should be.

```
<asp:button id="myButton" runat="server" text="Postback" onclientclick="alert('hello world');" />
```

if all you are doing is changing some visibility of some elements, you shouldn't even be doing a post back at all. just use an `input type="button"` and show/hide through javascript.

```
<input type="button" value="Next" id="btn_add_question" />

document.getElementById('btn_add_question').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('frm_course').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('question_div').style.visibility = 'visible';
    alert('hello world');
};
```

Comment: this is vb `Handles btn_add_question.Click` does this on the server side, you are talking about javascript

Comment: @Hogan you make a pointless postback to do things you could just do in javascript, it's bad for performance from a code and latency perspective.

Comment: What you say may be true.  HOWEVER, THIS IS STILL THE POSTERS QUESTION.  Thus the downvote.  There are any number of times I had to post an alert to a page from code behind which could not be done any other way.

Comment: @Hogan the answer i posted accomplishes exactly the same functionality as what the OP is trying to accomplish, without a postback. how is that a bad thing?

Comment: Have some imagination there are any number of cases (which have not been simplified to post here) which require the code he is showing.